# Firebase Flask API Deployment Error: /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found

Tags: python, firebase, docker, flask

i'm trying to deploy my flask REST onto firebase. I'm following this article: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579

I get this error when running `gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/id/flask-fire`.

Here are the relevant messages:

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [flask-fire] in project [project-name] region [europe-west1]
Deploying...
  Creating Revision... Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this rev
  ision might contain more information.
```

`/bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found`

Here's my Dockerfile :

```
# 1
FROM python:3.9

# 2
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip3 install gunicorn

# 3
COPY src/ /app
WORKDIR /app

# 4
ENV PORT 8080

# 5
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:application
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a ton in advance!

Also, here's my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Why are you installing Gunicorn with a `RUN` in your `Dockerfile` instead of just including it in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: it doesn't install through requirements.txt either, i've tried that